# Why is the OED's first reference to *irredentism* as late as 1886?

Tags: etymology, dates

*Irredentism* (from the Italian *irredento*, 'unredeemed') has a first reference in the OED as late as 1886. Yet irredentism, the problem which had plagued European statesmen for generations was deeply at issue in the unifications of both Germany and Italy in the mid 19th century.

Ethnic populations were never conveniently demarcated by lines on the map. It affected Germans living in Poland, Germans in Denmark, Austrians in the Italian states, Italians in the Balkans, Serbs in Bosnia, and was endemic to a continent of empires comprised of countless nationalities. The Austro-Hungarian Empire had a score of different ethnicities.  And the problem is still with us, and has emerged spectacularly in the last few days with the shooting down of an airliner by Russians living in an ostensibly Ukrainian territory.

Following the Treaty of Westphalia in 1648 Europe was destined for becoming a continent of nations, rather than one of Empires. So 'irredentism' was an issue from the start. Why does it not appear in English until 1886?

Comment: Not familiar with the history or etymology, but from your description, the fact that none of the affected nations were English-speaking may have something to do with it.

Comment: Looks to me like the (online by-subscription) OED's first example of irredentism is 1883, of irredentist 1882: "1883 *Standard* 30 Apr. 5/5   Irredentism is less powerful than the need felt by all the Central European States for mutual peace and safety." "1882 *Standard* 4 Aug. 5/7 Irredentist outrage and riot at Trieste."

Comment: The concept of the European [nation state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation_state) is itself relatively recent, so the specific kinds of aspiration embodied in the various irredentist movements there are similarly quite recent.

Comment: @ErikKowal Quite so. But the origins of nationalism were there in the 17th century and long predate the French Revolution which quintessentially embodied the idea.

Comment: @JeffSahol Good point, but Josh 61 I believe supplies the important clue. It was an Italian political movement referred to in English in 1882.

Comment: @ws2 - I think the question boils down to the extent to which  you distinguish between nationalism and irredentism.

Comment: @ErikKowal It was a feature of nationalist thinking. And it still is. I note on tonight's news that the train carrying the bodies of the dead airline passengers is destined not for Kiev but for Kharkiv, east of the Dneiper. The latter I suspect is seen as the Russian capital of the region whilst Kiev is Ukrainian. Irredentism is as endemic to modern Russia as it was to 19th-century Italy, as the recent seizure of the Crimea illustrates.

Comment: @WS2 - The irredentist desire to amend national borders presupposes the existence of those national borders (and hence nation states) in the first place. Irredentism is essentially an expression of dissatisfaction with *existing borders*. That's what I was getting at.

Comment: @ErikKowal Indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Irredentist](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Irredentism&searchmode=none)(n.)

> 1882, member of Italian political party which (after 1878) demanded the annexation of neighboring Italian-speaking regions (Trieste, S. Tyrol, Nice, Corsica, etc.), from Italian Irredentista, from (Italia) irredenta "unredeemed (Italy)." Related: Irredentism.

Source: Etymonline.com

Actually, the expression was coined by the Italian politician Matteo Renato Imbriani  in 1877, not that much before OED recorded it.

> *L'espressione "terre irredente", cioè non liberate, fu utilizzata la prima volta dal patriota e uomo politico italiano Matteo Renato Imbriani, nel 1877, ai funerali del padre Paolo Emilio; un giornalista viennese lo definì subito "irredentista" per dileggiarlo.*

Source: http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irredentismo

Comment: Very good point.